# Android updating database differentially

Tags: android, database

HI All,

I am developing an application which would  need to regularlay update the database from the server. I am planning to get the database from server in json format.

But I want to update the data for those records which have been updated on the server. I do not want to download the complete database but only the differential database so that data transfer is minimum each time.

What is the best way to achieve this? Any sample code available?

Rgds,
Sapan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put a *modified_date* column in the corresponding tables in the database and ensure it is updated by server(or some other mechanism such as using database provided facilities) whenever a row is updated/added. At any time you can request the records which have *modified_date* greater than the time when last query was executed. On your application you have to maintain the time when the data was last fetched.

Comment: thanks for the answer..this looks to be the simplest solution